# Find and replace in special CSV column with Python

Tags: python, csv, replace

Normally i do find and replace with the following code, which works like expected:

```
text = open("input.csv", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace("\"-\"", "\"\"")
x = open("output.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

Now i want do the same but in the special column. How can i setup the column (like column number or name), where find and replace things?

**Test data**: to delete is a `-`-sign in the column `Referer`

```
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| URL                                        | Timestamp           | Remote Host  | Method | Response Code | Bytes | Time Taken(ms) | User Agent                                                                                                                                                                                             | Referer | Verification Status |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| http://example.com/krankenversicherung.php | 18.05.2019 00:00:00 | 66.249.64.92 | GET    | 301           | 4     | 261            | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) | -       | Verified            |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| http://example.com/krankenversicherung.php | 18.05.2019 00:00:01 | 66.249.64.90 | GET    | 200           | 15688 | 296            | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) |         | Verified            |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| http://example.com/krankenversicherung.php | 18.05.2019 00:00:00 | 66.249.64.92 | GET    | 301           | 4     | 261            | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) | -       | Verified            |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| http://example.com/krankenversicherung.php | 18.05.2019 00:00:01 | 66.249.64.90 | GET    | 200           | 15688 | 296            | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) |         | Verified            |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| http://example.com/krankenversicherung.php | 18.05.2019 00:00:00 | 66.249.64.92 | GET    | 301           | 4     | 261            | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) | -       | Verified            |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| http://example.com/krankenversicherung.php | 18.05.2019 00:00:01 | 66.249.64.90 | GET    | 200           | 15688 | 296            | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) |         | Verified            |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| http://example.com/krankenversicherung.php | 18.05.2019 00:00:00 | 66.249.64.92 | GET    | 301           | 4     | 261            | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) |         | Verified            |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| http://example.com/krankenversicherung.php | 18.05.2019 00:00:01 | 66.249.64.90 | GET    | 200           | 15688 | 296            | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) |         | Verified            |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| http://example.com/krankenversicherung.php | 18.05.2019 00:00:00 | 66.249.64.92 | GET    | 301           | 4     | 261            | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) |         | Verified            |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Comment: post a testable `"input.csv"` content

Comment: now you see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `csv` library. That makes this really easy:

```
import csv
input_file = open('input.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('output.csv', 'w+', newline='')

reader = csv.reader(input_file, quotechar='|')
writer = csv.writer(output_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
for line in reader:
    line[7] = line[7].replace('-', '')  # change to correct replace and index values
    writer.writerow(line)
```

If you want to learn more about the `csv` library, I'd suggest reading [my blogpost](https://rooy.works/data/python-csv/).

Comment: Where in your code is a name or an index of column?

Comment: `line[1] = line[1]`, you can change the index.

Comment: It works, but not as expected. I need to delete `-` between `""`. But if i setup the replacement like `replace('\"-\"', '\"\"')` or even without escaping, like `replace('"-"', '""')` , the code replaces `"-"` with empty place. Quote signs are replaced too. In the code i cited above escaping of quote signs let them remain - in your code under all circumstances they are away.

Comment: @Evgeniy `replace('"-"', '""')` with this you replace all `"-"` with just `""`.

Comment: No, it works even not consistently. Look at screenshot: https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1432/4557320379.png

Comment: Could you send a screenshot of the input.csv file?

Comment: see in my first post

Comment: @Evgeniy I mean of the actual raw file, not formatted.

Comment: @Evgeniy `replace('-', '')` does the job. The CSV library removes quotes from the actual values when parsing the file. Later, when writing the file back to the CSV format, they are added again.

Comment: No, it doesn't. As previously, it replaces quots, but not the minus. https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1433/3116990247.png

Comment: @Evgeniy please see the updated code example in the answer.